# Parsing an element which may or may not exists with HXT library

Tags: haskell, hxt

I have a problem with HXT.
i wanna parse an owl file and  i have a problem with my arrow, because he dont wanna parse a tree !
I saw that the problem is that one: 
Firstly , the code :

```
import System.Environment  --para uso do getArgs

import Data.List.Split (splitOn)


data Class = Class {
                    name ::String,
                    subClassOf ::String
               } deriving (Show,Eq)


main = do
   [src]<- getArgs
   parser <- runX(readDocument [ withValidate no] src  >>> getClass)
   print parser


parseClass = ifA (hasAttr "rdf:about")  (getAttrValue "rdf:about")  (getAttrValue "rdf:ID")

parseSubClass = getAttrValue "rdf:resource"



split l = if(length (splitOn "#" l) >1) then (splitOn "#" l !! 1) else l


atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)

getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- parseClass -< l
    s <- atTag "rdfs:subClassOf" -< l
    subClass <- parseSubClass -< s
    returnA -< Class { name = (split className), subClassOf = (split subClass) }
```

with that i should be able to parse on the owl file each nodes where it exists this example :

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="Damien">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="PurchaseableItem"/>
</owl:Class>
```

But, when i want to parse a tree like that , it simply doesnt compute and throw it away !

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="&camera;BodyWithNonAdjustableShutterSpeed">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="&camera;Body"/>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&camera;shutter-speed"/>
                    <owl:cardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">0</owl:cardinality>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

Why ? Because the Subclass node doesnt exist ! But i want the Class available there and put it on my data even if the subclass doesnt exists !
So, how is that possible to do it ?

---

My newest version:

```
import System.Environment  --para uso do getArgs
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

data Class = Class {
                    name ::String,
                    subClassOf :: String
               } deriving (Show,Eq)

main = do
   [src]<- getArgs
   parser <- runX(readDocument [ withValidate no] src  >>> getClass)
   print parser

parseClass = ifA (hasAttr "rdf:about")  (getAttrValue "rdf:about")  (getAttrValue "rdf:ID")
parseSubClass = (getAttrValue "rdf:resource") `orElse` arr (const "" )

--Test  (é preciso rever esta definição) uma falha se o nome tiver o "#"
split l = if(length (splitOn "#" l) >1) then (splitOn "#" l !! 1) else l

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)
getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- parseClass -< l
    s <- atTag "rdfs:subClassOf" -< l
    subClass <- parseSubClass -< s
    returnA -< Class { name = (split className), subClassOf = split subClass }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what you want when the SubClass node doesn't exist. As I see it, you have two choices:

- A missing SubClass node means that `subClass` is the empty string. In that case, simply change your parser to fall back to the empty string when the arrow built around `atTag "rdfs:subClassOf"` fails:

  ```
  getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
      proc l -> do
      className <- parseClass -< l
      subClass <- getSubClass -< l
      returnA -< Class { name = split className, subClassOf = split subClass }
      where
        getSubClass =
          (atTag "rdfs:subClassOf" >>> parseSubClass) `orElse` arr (const "")
  ```
- A missing SubClass node means that `subClass` is `Nothing`. This requires changing your data definition so that `subClassOf` is of type `Maybe String`, but after that it's fairly similar to the previous answer:

  ```
  getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
      proc l -> do
      className <- parseClass -< l
      subClass <- getSubClass -< l
      returnA -< Class { name = split className, subClassOf = fmap split subClass }
      where
        getSubClass =
          (atTag "rdfs:subClassOf" >>> parseSubClass >>> arr Just)
          `orElse` arr (const Nothing)
  ```

Just so we're clear, because you say that this isn't working in the comments, here's exactly the full program I'm running, which works fine for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
import System.Environment  --para uso do getArgs
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

data Class = Class {
                    name ::String,
                    subClassOf ::String
               } deriving (Show,Eq)

main = do
   [src]<- getArgs
   parser <- runX(readDocument [ withValidate no] src  >>> getClass)
   print parser

parseClass = ifA (hasAttr "rdf:about")
             (getAttrValue "rdf:about")
             (getAttrValue "rdf:ID")

parseSubClass = getAttrValue "rdf:resource"

split l = if(length (splitOn "#" l) >1) then (splitOn "#" l !! 1) else l

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)

getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- parseClass -< l
    subClass <- getSubClass -< l
    returnA -< Class { name = split className, subClassOf = split subClass }
    where
      getSubClass =
        (atTag "rdfs:subClassOf" >>> parseSubClass)
        `orElse` arr (const "")
```

Note that if you really don't want to combine multple arrow steps with `>>>` or `<<<`, another possibility is to use an inner `proc`:

```
getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- parseClass -< l
    subClass <- (proc l' -> do
      s <- atTag "rdfs:subClassOf" -< l'
      parseSubClass -< s)
      `orElse` constA "" -< l
    returnA -< Class { name = split className, subClassOf = split subClass}
```

Comment: I tried your first version and it continues to have the same problem ! It continues to throw away

Comment: And i did your second version with the use of Maybe , and it doesnt work also. :/

Comment: There was indeed an error in my `Maybe` version (forgot an `fmap`, now fixed), but the empty string version works fine for me. I posted the whole code so that you can check what's different.

Comment: I reedited my post and put my code there, what's the difference between yours and mine ??

Comment: The difference is that you need the `orElse` to cover the thing that's failing. It isn't `getAttrValue` that's failing, it's `atTag "rdfs:subClassOf"`. In my version, the `orElse` covers the `atTag` result.

Comment: hummm i think i got it ! :) and if i wanna do with my version, is there any way on how to do it ?

Comment: First, take the `orElse` bit out of the `parseSubClass`. Then, see the  bit I just added. (note that `constA` is just `arr . const`)